# How use Google Analytics Reporting api with new GA4 accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-data-api

Before GA4 i use a custom php dashboard with dimensions and metrics for reporting stats.
I use VIEW_ID for having my stats.
Here my code :

> function initializeAnalytics(){
>
> ```
> $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '/google-api-php-client/service-account-credentials.json';
>
> $client = new Google_Client();
>
> $client->setApplicationName("Reporting");
>
> $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
>
> $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
>
> $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
>
> return $analytics;
> ```
>
> }
>
> function getResults($analytics) {
>
> ```
> return $analytics->data_ga->get(
>
> 'ga:VIEW_ID',
>
> '30daysAgo',
>
> 'yesterday',
>
> 'ga:users',
>
> array('dimensions'=>'ga:date')
>
> );
> ```
>
> }
>
> function printResults($results) {
>
> ```
> if (!empty($results->getRows()) && count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
>
> $rows = $results->getRows();
>
> return $rows[0][0];
>
> } else {
>
> return 0;
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();

$results = getResults($analytics);

echo printResults($results);

It's workinig for all UA-XXXXXX-X properties with VIEW_ID.

But now with GA4 Properties, there is no VIEW_ID and i don't know how having this report using the new G_MEASUREMENT_ID. There is no guide for PHP and it still in alpha version...

Please help, my custom dashboard doesn't work with GA4 :(

Answer (score 7):

The Google analytics Reporting API doesn't support GA4 accounts.  You will need to use the new [analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data)  There is currently very little documentation for this api but im sure it will arrive in the coming months.

You will need to rewrite your custom dashboard to use this new api, It should be available to you as part of the PHP client library.

```
  "name": string,
  "dimensions": [
    {
      object (DimensionMetadata)
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      object (MetricMetadata)
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, so i will continue to use old Universal Analytics property... Hope Google publish PHP guide soon...

Comment: Ping me if one doesn't appear soon i will take care of it.

Comment: Bat, the PHP client library for the Google Analytics Data API is going to be published soon, please stay tuned! You will be able to find the client here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data#client_libraries

Comment: Thanks Ilya Kuloshov, i stay tuned :)

Comment: @IlyaKuleshov still no sign of the PHP library for GA Data API ?

Comment: There is now @GabrielSpiteri

Comment: THANK YOU! I searched high and low and you had the answer i was looking for. Follow the steps on the link he provided to connect and pull data from GA4!

Answer (score 0):

For GA4 Reporting API , new APIs are available this link can be referred for the set up steps [Step For migrating api of UA to GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4)

and using this query explorer tool you can build the query parameter
[Query Explorer tool](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/)

Answer (score -2):

To show reports in My admin dashboard,
i ended up using google data studio[Google Data studio](https://datastudio.google.com/)

Importing GA4 data in it and made reports.

There's share button which gives a link to view the reports,

Used IFRAME tag in my admin dashboard with (google data studio report) view link